# I got a confusing error regarding animate.css in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, animate.css

[everything compiled correctly prior to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZQtC.png)

tried to look up solutions on net but unfortunately couldnt find anything

in case image didnt load:

Failed to compile

./node_modules/animate.css/animate.css:8:1
Syntax error: Selector ":root" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

6 |  * Copyright (c) 2020 Animate.css
7 |  */

> 8 | :root {
> |                           ^
> 9 |   --animate-duration: 1s;
> 10 |   --animate-delay: 1s;

Comment: I think its something to do with making it a global class.  Citation --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279517/using-css-modules-how-do-i-define-a-global-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use :global css classes - css modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345353/how-can-i-use-global-css-classes-css-modules)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.